# php request downloading the actual script after changing php version with .htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I work on a shared server that has multiple php versions. I read on the internet that simply adding a .htaccess file with the following line in my folder dictates what version of php will be used when the scripts in that folder run: "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php"

After adding this line when i call myScript.php i get the actual content of the file

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Accessing the script in the browser downloads a copy of the script

What am i doing wront ?

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is downloading the script that means the php module or handler is not loaded.

check the php module in httpd.conf. do not forget to restart apache.